# Can't access network shared drive, "Windows cannot access \\COMPUTER\NAS" even though it's shared to everyone

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, file-sharing, sharing, workgroup

I wanted to use an unused *partition* of a slow computer (mainly used to run Steam Link) running Windows 10 Home as a *share* for my other Windows 10 computers. However, I can't seem to be able to access the *share*. I already shared it to "everyone" in the sharing tab although I only wanted to access it from a specific computer.

My other computer can share its folders to the *share server* just fine but not the other way around.

I checked the "share permissions" tab in the properties section and tried to add my user on my other computer but it could only search for local users.

I have them all in the default home workgroup and they're all set to a private network. What other things can I try?

Edit:

Used both `net use E: \\ipofshareserver\shareserver` and `net use E: \\ipofshareserver\shareserver /user:nameoflocaluser (no password)`, both times I ran it said the command ran successfully and the drive appeared in This PC > network location, but when I tried to open it it still gave the same error.

Comment: Check if your NAS is older and is restricted to SMBv1. It will not work with Windows 10 if that is the case.

Comment: I don't think it is; isn't SMBv1 disabled by default on W10?

Comment: Windows 10 will not allow SMBv1.  There are registry changes to allow it but it is very unsafe.

Comment: Try mapping by IP address. NET USE Z:  \\IP of NAS\Folder and see if that works.

Comment: Windows 10 Home is not a NAS. If you want a NAS then use a NAS OS.

Comment: I just want to call it a NAS, technically doesn't Windows file sharing make it a NAS? Please don't argue semantics, I just want to get help.

Comment: If I do NET USE \\ip, it reports that the command completed successfully. The partition now shows up in This PC > Network Locations. However, it still displays the cannot access message

Comment: Using the correct terminology will really help towards the correct solution. You are mapping a share, not a partition. You are connecting to another windows 10 computer, not a NAS. Try mapping the share using the IP address from within the file tab of windows explorer. If you map via a cmd window, due to permissions you may only be able to access the share from the command window only.

Comment: @Beefmaster5000BCE _(Terminology would be a share server)_ Without the exact error messages populated on the share server _(see Event Viewer - you may have to google for the log location within it)_, it's hard to troubleshoot; generally, you need to create a local user on the share server to be used to login to the shares from other clients.

Comment: Alright, changed everything as per @JohnnyVegas's insistence. 
Where can I see sharing error messages on Event Viewer? I can't see anything related to sharing there.

I made a local account with the same username but with a password and tried to use the "map network drive" option. It seemed to recognize the username and asked for a password. When I entered the local account on the share server's password, it said that it was mapped with a different user name and password and to disconnect any existing mappings to the network share if using a different user name and password.

Comment: Well, using ```net use \\computerip\folder``` with a password protected local user user account with a password did the trick. I couldn't access it without the password, even if password protected sharing was turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a password protected local user account with the same user name to map the drive with `net use \\ip\folder` command. Works fine now and appears in This PC. I used the /p thingy to net use to keep it appearing when my PC restarts.